# Drools rule to check whether Hashmap key present

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am using below rule to check if hashmap key is equals to "templateUUID". Below rule running with no error but the value is not getting changed in required json.

```
rule "Update HashMap Value"
when
    $mobiSubset: Mobi_Subset()
    $fileNameMappings: Map(this == $mobiSubset.fileNameMappings)
    $key: String(this == "templateUUID") from $fileNameMappings.keySet()
then
    $fileNameMappings.put($key, "metadata.json");
end

Json: 
{
    "titleId" : "3510585",
    "contentType" : "Movie",
    "titleBrief" : "Annihilation",
    "titleBriefHD" : "Annihilation HD",
    "downloadRights" : true,
    "downloadNoHours" : 720,
    "streamingRights" : true,
    "fileNameMappings":
    {
      "bignight_3519599.scc":"bignight_3519599.scc",
      "bignight_3519599.mp4":"bignight_3519599.mp4",
      "templateUUID":"metadata.xml"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you're doing it this way, but here's the correct syntax.

```
rule "Update HashMap Value"
when
    // Get the map
    Mobi_Subset( $fileNameMappings: fileNameMappings != null )

    // Check that the key exists
    exists( String( this == "templateUUID" ) from $fileNameMappings.keySet() )
then
    // Update the value
    $fileNameMappings.put("templateUUID", "metadata.json");
end
```

If you were just trying to replace metadata.xml with metadata.json, I'd've done it like this:

```
rule "Update HashMap Value"
when
    Mobi_Subset( $fileNameMappings: fileNameMappings != null )
    Map( this["templateUUID"] == "metadata.xml" ) from $fileNameMappings
then
    $fileNameMappings.put("templateUUID", "metadata.json");
end
```

The first version will blindly overwrite *anything* in the map in the `templateUUID` field. The second version will only update it to be metadata.json if it were originally metadata.xml. Both versions will not do anything if the key is not present.